# Script Bash - cp Target is not a Directory - Using variables

Tags: git-bash

I know that this type of questions maybe were duplicated. But in my case, I'm use a variable that contains the destination directory and the error says, that is not a valid directory.

*cp target var2 is not a directory*

Now, this is my code, I'm trying to copy all images from the folder images **(contained in Desktop)** to the folder photos **(In desktop too and empty).** I use GIT Bash for Windows 10

```
function pause(){

    read -p "$*"
}

echo "Help: Use the bar / to separate the directory names"
echo ""

echo "Enter the directory location"
read var1

echo "Enter the destinity directory location"
read var2

for var1 in "var2"
do
    cp * var1 var2
done

echo ""
pause "Press [ENTER] to continue..."
```

What's my mistake? Thanks!

When i execute the script, the directory I use is:

C:/Users/Mauri/Desktop/images

And the var2 is:

C:/Users/Mauri/Desktop/photos

With this code into the for:

cp -r * $var1 $var2

Was moved **all** archives in the desktop to photos folder, **It's not my objetive,** I want to move **only the images** contained on the image folder in the desktop to the empty folder photos in the desktop too.

Comment: Are you missing the dollar in `cp * $var1 $var2`?

Comment: Now the error says: cp: cannot stat 'var2': No such file or directory. I used $ on variables, for example: cp -r $var1 $var2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `for` loop, it would be great if we could run `cp "$var1/"*.{jpg,png,gif} "$var2"`. That would be an easy way to copy all of the files with extension `jpg`, `png`, or `gif` from `$var1` into `$var2`. Unfortunately, that command fails if there happen to be no files with one of the given extensions, for example if we have several `jpg` files but no `gif`s.

So we have to make things a little more complicated, and our answer is the `find` command, as shown below. If you want to add more image file types, just add another set of `-o -name '*.EXT'` within the parentheses, where `EXT` is the file extension you want.

```
function pause(){

    read -p "$*"
}

echo "Help: Use the bar / to separate the directory names"
echo ""

echo "Enter the source directory"
read source

echo "Enter the destination directory"
read dest

find $source \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.png' \) -exec cp -prv {} $dest \;

echo ""
pause "Press [ENTER] to continue..."
```

The `-prv` flag on `cp` means preserve attributes, copy recursively, and use verbose mode (print what has been copied).